# Dynamically copy input of two fields and paste it in third field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to copy the First Name and Last Name field into another 'Username' field dynamically. The Username field should also be lowercase and have a hyphen in the middle. So for example,

- if First Name = John
- and Last Name = Smith
- then Username (dynamically-created) = john-smith

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little. Maybe show us the HTML that contains these inputs, and any code you've tried?

Comment: seems pretty straight forward, what did you try?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with plain JavaScript. I'm assuming there is a button of some sort to add the fields together. Also assuming that your *Input* is `<input>` text boxes.

```js
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
  var lastName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
  var userName = document.getElementById("userName");

  userName.value = firstName.toLowerCase() + "-" + lastName.toLowerCase();
});
```

```html
<input id="firstName" type="text" placeholder="First Name" />
<input id="lastName" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" />
<input id="userName" type="text" placeholder="Username" disabled />
<button id="button">Create Username</button>
```

To make it dynamically update, use `onkeydown` or `onkeyup`. Follow [kemotoe's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46854863/dynamically-copy-input-of-two-fields-and-paste-it-in-third-field/46855065#46855065) answer.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is using `onkeyup`event to make it dynamic. This also takes care of any uppercase letters.

```js
function generateFullName() {
  document.getElementById("username").innerText =
  document.getElementById("fName").value.toLowerCase() +
  "-" +
  document.getElementById("lName").value.toLowerCase();
}
```

```html
First Name <input type="text" id="fName" onkeyup="generateFullName()" />
Last Name <input type="text" id="lName" onkeyup="generateFullName()" /> <br/>
Username: <span id="username" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with jquery, too. This is a working example.
[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/my6dwf2h/1/)

**HTML**

```
<input id = "first"> <br> <br>
<input id = "last"> <br> <br>
<input id = "username">
<button id ="generate">Generate</button>
```

**JS**

```
$("#generate").on("click", () => {
        let first = $("#first").val()
        let last = $("#last").val()
        $("#username").val(first+ "-"+last)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#firstName').change(updateUsername());
$('#lastName').change(updateUsername());
function updateUsername(){
  $('#userName').val($('#firstName').val().toLowerCase() +"-"+$('#lastName').val().toLowerCase() );
}
```

Bind with change event to update the user name field

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [onkeypress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeypress) event.

It would look like this

```js
document.querySelector('.form').addEventListener(("keypress"), () => {
    //Code to edit the username field goes here
    //Try pressing a key inside the form
 alert('Hi');
});
```

```html
<form class='form'>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text" >
  <input type="text" class='username'>
</form>
```